# How are event listeners implemented in browsers and native OSs?

Tags: events, functional-programming, operating-system, dom-events

At a low level,

1. How does Chrome know that my mouse entered the screen?
2. How does my alarm clock on my Iphone know that it is 9:00am 7 hours after I set the alarm?

---

1. Fundamentally is there repeated polling going on?

Or is there some sort of in built event loop (in both cases) that we simply register functions to... these functions then get automagically called in our apps as needed with the right contexts?

2. Is this event loop something all OS's expose? I thought we needed closures and functions as first class objects.. how does it work in OS's like iOS where Objective-C (and not js or some functional language) is the core language?

Comment: This is too broad for a straightforward answer - Windows is not Android is not iOS, Chrome is not Firefox. Try asking a more directed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most systems that have grown over time, it is somewhat complicated. Different things are done at different levels. For example: do you remember [IRQs?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request) We don't worry about them much today in our higher level programs, but a decade or two ago you had to make sure your hardware didn't use conflicting IRQs. These were literally a hardware callback setup (still are in updated form (I can't post enough links but the previous wikipedia article has a link to APIC architecture), but I haven't had to deal with them in years.). The system would have some small routine and the CPU (this was on x86 CPUs) would assign the address of that code to an "interrupt request line". Then when the hardware on the other end of that line signaled, the CPU would drop everything and jump to that bit of code.

There are more complicated cases though, for example question (i). There obviously is no hardware interrupt for your mouse cursor entering the Chrome window. What happens is that the OS catches hardware interrupts for mouse movement and uses that information to update the cursor position (of course there are libraries like [Allegro](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/) which can give you hardware cursors, and further muddy the waters of inquiry). Then the OS has a list of programs that have requested to be notified (and how to notify each) about various mouse movement events, and the OS goes through that list and calculates which programs should be told.

(ii) is actually simpler because one of the most common interrupts is a timer. Generally the OS still acts as a buffer between the hardware and the program as in (i).

(1) While you will often want to do something at regular intervals your programs generally won't need to poll repeatedly. However the OS may do things differently. For example: those interrupt routines that I mentioned earlier have to be very fast to avoid having the interrupt interrupted or ignoring other events. So one common strategy was to have the interrupt routine just set some memory saying something happened and then have the normal portion of the OS loop poll those memory locations regularly. This however is a systems issue not an applications one.

(2) Most Operating Systems I am familiar with offer event callback APIs. Some, like the old MS-DOS, really didn't give you much API and just let you assign your own interrupt handlers, (for both hardware and software interrupts.) Most modern OSs expose this functionality through the scheduler. A program will give up control while waiting for a specific event or set of events. Various libraries hide this inside their own internal event loop. Callback functions are a common way of dealing with these library's internal event loops. I am not entirely qualified to speak to Objective C, but since it is a strict superset of C (according to Wikipedia) it can use callbacks in the same manner C does (I imagine may be considered bad style though).

I hope that that gives you some of the information you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This was great. I understand that my question was very broad..but this was VERY helpful. It also appears that my hunches weren't too far off. Is there an OS book you recommend to learn this stuff properly?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Unfortunately I don't know of a book about this topic. I am sure that such books exist, but I learned what I know from many small scattered sources(tutorials, manuals, poking around in libraries, articles, etc.). Sorry I can't help more. Perhaps some third party reading this could recommend a good book on OS design or schedulers. There might even be a reference request for such already on this site.